# Redundant col classes in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I do a lot of this in Bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">...
```

Is there any short-hand CSS classes that mean "use this col size for all viewport sizes?" Something like this below, perhaps?

```
<div class="col-all-4">...
```

Comment: Just use the lowest target size as  `col-sm-4`

Comment: Use `col-xs-4` for all viewports, but normally you'd want to let cols stack on the smallest viewports so you'd just use `col-sm-4`.. This implies `col-xs-12 col-sm-4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `media queries` that modifies the `col-*` classnames works around a `min-width` and no limit as `max-width` value like:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  //For md
}
```

And the default value for `xs` elements. Therefore what you can do to avoid the redundant `col` names is just call the smallest device you want with that number of columns:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">...
```

must be

```
<div class="col-sm-4">...
```

Answer (score 1):

For all the screen sizes you need `xs` it has the ability to cater all the screens if other not specified.

```
<div class-"col-xs-4"> .... </div>
```

**FYI**

If `xs` you specify `col-xs-4` and not specify for other screens then it is equivalent to `col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4`.

If you specify `col-xs-8 and col-md-4` then it means `col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4`

So in other words higher screens overrides the lower screen column's width. But lower screen doesn't show this property.